# Bibliographic citations in ScalaDoc

Tags: bibtex, scaladoc, citations

Several documentations tools support generating bibliographies and citation markers. For example, the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/161537d9-6f89-42ef-9c51-3a15ef94df65.htm) allows defining `<reference>`s and referring to them by `<cite>` MAML tags. [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#citations_for_pdf_output) supports many bibliography formats, including BibTeX and respects citations styles when exporting pdfs with Pandoc.

*Is there any way to place references into Scaladoc comments?* Best I could think about is including the BibTeX entry as verbatim `{{{ }}}` code, which is fine where a class or method is based on a whole single paper. However, referring to specific pages or figures (i.e. this method implements the pseudocode from p.26, Fig. 3.a of so-and-so) is awkward this way. I would very much prefer a single .bib file per project and `\cite` tags.